# Check the parity of the Green and Blue values into an image

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, rgb

I have an array **ver** of shape (9,8,2) which I extracted from an image.
What I'm searching to do is to iterate over the pixels of this array, check if Green and Blue values have a different parity, if so, put the result **True** in a list, and do the same for each lines.

```
ver = im_arr[:9,:8,1:3]
```

Here I took the first 9 lines of the image, the 8 first pixels, and I've extracted the columns to have only the Green and Blue values.
I now know how to with a 2D array like that :

```
cf = cf[:,1:3]
jou = (cf.sum(1)%2).astype(bool)
```

But in this case, with a 3D array, I really don't know how to do, I tried with three for loop, but it doesn't work :

```
  for i in range(ver.shape[0]):
         for y in range(ver.shape[1]):
           for z in range(ver.shape[2]):
                juju[i,y,z] = (ver.sum(1)%2).astype(bool)
```

Comment: Can you explain briefly what you mean by parity?

Comment: If I extract a pixel from an image I have an array RGB like this for example [5 140 24] and I want to check if 140 and 24 have the same parity (G and B values) here yes they are even so return False. if they have different parity -> True

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], including some input and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 100, 3))
subset = image[:9, :8, 1:]

mask = ~np.all(np.remainder(subset, 2) == 0, axis=-1)
```

This code generates a random image and extracts the subset. Then it checks that the remainder of all numbers in the array are divisible by 2. The np.all call checks if across the last dimension, all values are True and returns True if so, False otherwise. To get the mask you want I just negate the result with ~

Edit to add a solution that checks whether both values across dimensions are either equal or odd.

```
import numpy as np

image = np.random.randint(0, 255, (100, 100, 3))
subset = image[:9, :8, 1:]

even = np.remainder(subset, 2) == 0
mask = ~np.equal(even[..., 0], even[..., 1])
```

Comment: I noticied that it doesn't work for odd numbers like [133 201] , it also returns True , and it must return False because they are of the same parity (odd)

Comment: Ahh I may have mis-interpreted the problem. I assumed he just wanted to check for the even case, not both. I'll update the answer to include one that checks if both are the same no matter even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

If you mask the LSB of the Green and Blue channels and add them, you can only get:

```
0 + 0 = 0
0 + 1 = 1  <--- THIS
1 + 0 = 1  <--- THIS
1 + 1 = 2
```

So, you want to identify where they add up to 1, i.e. they are different:

```
mask = np.sum((ver & 1), axis=-1) == 1
```

Comment: great thanks ! What does mean the  -1 for the axis ?

Comment: It means the **last** axis. So axis=0 would be summing down the columns, axis=1 would be summing across along the rows and axis=2 is adding/summing across the channels. Axis=2 is the same as axis=-1 because 2 is the last axis.